# Anybody using Aurelia with graphql

Tags: aurelia

My backend exposes graphql wanted to know what is your experience with aurelia and graphql.

Are there any good libraries out there to use?

I could only find a minimal apollo bind library here https://github.com/stphdenis/aurelia-apollo-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aurelia does not impose any restrictions. From examples I see in [graphql docs](http://graphql.org/code/#javascript) there is nothing you can't do with Aurelia.

There is no need in specific bridge or wrapper library.

Comment: You are right, but there is a lot of stuff that a proper graphql client can do, caching for example and query composition. I did not managed to make aurelia work with any of he popular clients unfortunately.

Comment: hit the https://discourse.aurelia.io you would probably convince someone to work with you on one

Comment: Will consider this for the next project.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use this Angular 9 sample https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GifdPhc_OWU
You will need the same GraphQL queries generator. And a similar way of calling a back-end.

I guess it is even possible to write content item templates in Aurelia syntax in place of Liquid templates of content type definitions, gather them to front-end along with JSON and render together. I would try to achieve that.